# Как задать для TextBlock максимальное количество строк?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

В данный момент меня интересует именно одна строка, но универсальное решение (для Х строк), конечно, будет лучше.

Нашел в интернетах несколько решений.

- **Использовать `TextBox` вместо `TextBlock`**. Но я не хочу только ради этого использовать не предназначенный для моих целей элемент
  управления. К тому же, возможно мне придется форматировать текст,
  поэтому мне идеально подходит именно `TextBlock`
- **Использовать фиксированные значения шрифта и высоты строки.** Мне это не подходит из религиозных соображений. Я не люблю железные
  интерфейсы, мне нравятся резиновые. Тем более я оставляю подобные величины на выбор системы. А если я в одном месте укажу значение размера шрифта, придется делать это во всем приложении. Иначе при определенных обстоятельствах это может всплыть наружу.

Интересуют более универсальные решения. Пока что действительно склоняюсь к использованию `TextBox`, но надеюсь на вашу и свою изобретательность :)

Дополнение:

Конкретно к моему случаю (одна строка) нашел решение - не использовать перенос и прогнать текст через конвертер, в котором удалить все переносы строк. Не очень хочется это делать, потому что в моем конкретном случае, я хочу чтобы отображалась именно верхняя строка текста, а не все, что поместится по ширине. Хотя на данный момент это решение в приоритете - не найдя лучшее, использую его.

Так же в конвертере можно отделить от всего текста верхнюю строку и вернуть только ее. Но хотелось бы найти решение совсем без конвертера, если это возможно. :)

Comment: Думаю лучший вариант будет через [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx). Берите в конвертере символы до переноса и рубите лишние символы.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик, так и сделал изначально.

Answer (score 1):

Или так, используйте вместо **Text** свойство **FixedText**

```
public class FixedTextBlock : System.Windows.Controls.TextBlock
{
  public static DependencyProperty FixedText_Property = DependencyProperty.Register("FixedText", typeof(string), typeof(FixedTextBlock));
  public static DependencyProperty TextLength_Property = DependencyProperty.Register("TextLength", typeof(int), typeof(FixedTextBlock));
  public FixedTextBlock() : base() 
  {
    TextLength = int.MaxValue;
  }
  public int TextLength 
  {
    get 
    { 
      return (int)GetValue(TextLength_Property); 
    } 
    set 
    { 
      SetValue(TextLength_Property, value);  
      if (FixedText.Length > TextLength) 
        FixedText = FixedText; 
    } 
  }
  public string FixedText 
  { 
    get 
    { 
      return (string)GetValue(FixedText_Property); 
    } 
    set 
    { 
      int index = value.IndexOf('\n'); 
      SetValue(FixedText_Property, value.Substring(0, Math.Min(TextLength, index >= 0 ? index : value.Length))); 
      Text = FixedText; 
    } 
  }
}
```

UPD: Улучшил логику

Comment: Хороший пример, но цель не оправдывает средства )

Comment: Вы писали "Не очень хочется это делать, потому что в моем конкретном случае, я хочу чтобы отображалась именно верхняя строка текста, а не все, что поместится по ширине. Хотя на данный момент это решение в приоритете - не найдя лучшее, использую его." я просто реализовал альтернативный способ без конвертера

Comment: Извини. Говоря без конвертера я имел ввиду без кода C#. Как то и не предполагал, что для решения данной задачи кто то предложит сваять собственный контрол с блекджеком )